# Use Polymer 2.0 component in Polymer 3.0 app

Tags: polymer, web-component, polymer-2.x, polymer-3.x

Currently I migrate a Polymer 2.0 app to Polymer 3.0. But at the moment understandably a lot of components are still not migrated, yet (like e.g vaadin-gid as one example).

How can I use these Polymer 2 components in my migrated Polymer 3 app?

Comment: Vaadin components (at least grid, see https://vaadin.com/components/vaadin-grid) do have "converted Polymer 3 compatible version" available. So bad example, but I think the topic itself is intresting...

Comment: I write a example in: https://github.com/herberthobregon/polymer2-3 It works but the polymer team has not answered me if the implementation is correct, but works

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I wasn't aware of the of the "converted Components". That will help me at least for the Vaadin-Components

Comment: isn't this the purpose of the modulizer, as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/50445580/521598 ?

Comment: @mishu: Yes, you are right, that's the purpose of the modulizer. In fact I have used it to migrate all my components. But I'm looking for a solution I do not have to migrate all the third-party componen, too

Answer (score 1):

basicly add this code in `<head>` and delete `/bower_components/polymer` folder

```
<script type="module">
        import {PolymerElement} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';

        window.Polymer = {
            Element: PolymerElement
        };

        window.loadElement = function(filename) {
            var l = document.createElement('link');
            l.rel = 'import';
            l.href = filename
            var h = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
            h.parentNode.insertBefore(l, h);
        }
        // Load de main element
        loadElement('/main-poly2.html');
</script>
```

load polymer 3 elements in polymer 2

```
<script type="module">
        import './poly3-element'

        class MainPoly2 extends Polymer.Element {
            ...
        }
</script>
```

load polymer 2 elements in polymer 3

```
import {PolymerElement, html} from '/node_modules/@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';
loadElement('/poly2-element.html');

class Poly3Element extends PolymerElement {
    ....
}
```

I write a example in:

https://github.com/herberthobregon/polymer2-3

It works but the polymer team has not answered me if the implementation is correct, but works

Comment: Nice workaround, it works. Thanks! The only drawback is that you can not manage how often different dependencies are loaded - even different Polymer versions may be loaded. But for now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

my solutions was upgrade the polymer 2.0 elements to polymer 3.0, using  polymer-modulizer

[https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/upgrade][1]