# Using Google Web Components elements in polymer 3

Tags: polymer, google-web-component, polymer-3.x

How can we install Google Web Components elements in polymer 3

Example - using google-youtube or many more elements can't support npm install yet!

https://www.webcomponents.org/element/GoogleWebComponents/google-youtube

Is anyone figured out installing this for polymer 3.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to install it will polymer modulizer

`npm install -g polymer-modulizer`

you'll need to have bower installed as well, then in your repo you can run

`modulizer GoogleWebComponents/google-youtube`

that will download and convert the component to the folder `modulizer_workspace`

https://github.com/Polymer/polymer-modulizer#workspace-mode

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this. Can we do something to convert other components like - https://github.com/FabricElements/skeleton-carousel ...?

Comment: Getting error on running - modulizer GoogleWebComponents/google-youtube
 ::  
Unhandled Rejection at: Promise  Promise {
  <rejected> Error: --npm-version required

Answer (score 1):

simply:

```
npm install -g polymer-modulizer
git clone https://github.com/GoogleWebComponents/google-youtube.git
cd google-youtube
modulizer --out .
```

> copy the new folder "google-youtube" and paste in your proyect in **node_modules**

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this. Can we do something to convert other components like - https://github.com/FabricElements/skeleton-carousel ...?

Comment: After following and import ..
import '@polymer/google-youtube/modulizer_out/google-youtube.js';

Error: Uncaught ReferenceError: Polymer is not defined
    at google-youtube.js:42

Comment: try add this line in JS file, import {Polymer,html} from "@polymer/polymer/polymer-legacy.js"; ++++ AND++. make sure Polymer({
  _template: html` ++++ NOT +++ Polymer({
  _template: Polymer,html`

Answer (score 1):

The modulizer didn't work for me, thus if just simply used an iframe to integrate a video. Since I don't need any of the google-youtube webcomponent properties this works fine for my website.

```
<iframe 
  class="video-frame"
  src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/[[videoId]]"
  allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen"
  mozallowfullscreen="mozallowfullscreen" 
  msallowfullscreen="msallowfullscreen" 
  oallowfullscreen="oallowfullscreen" 
  webkitallowfullscreen="webkitallowfullscreen"
  frameBorder="0">
</iframe>
```

see also [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_youtube.asp) for additional query parameters like autoplay etc.

Answer (score 0):

well you can pull the component from github and used the polymer 3 modulizer to covert the element to a polymer 3 element and they just use it on to your application.

Comment: How can we do this..?